# Capture all repetitions of a group using Python regular expression

Tags: python, regex, string

I have an input of the following format:

```
<integer>: <word> ... # <comment>
```

where `...` can represent one or more `<word>` strings.

Here is an example:

```
1: foo bar baz # This is an example
```

I want to split this input apart with regular expression and return a tuple that contains the integer followed by each word. For the above example, I want:

```
(1, 'foo', 'bar', 'baz')
```

This is what I have tried.

```
>>> re.match('(\d+):( \w+)+', '1: foo bar baz # This is an example').groups()
('1', ' baz')
```

I am getting the integer and the last word only. How do I get the integer and all the words that the regex matches?

Comment: Any reason you need to do this with regular expressions?

Comment: @Decency I am using regular expression to validate the example input, so I thought I could use it to extract the tokens I need as well.

Comment: The problem is that `groups()` return *one* match per group. If a group did multiple matches it only returns the last match (as you already seen). If you want the whole thing you'd have to use a *single* group, such as: `(\d+):(( \w+)+)`. Then you'll have to split the content matched by the outer group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably make it a lot clearer with simple string manipulation.

```
my_string = '1: foo bar baz'
num_string, word_string = my_string.split(':')
num = int(num_string)
words = word_string.strip().split(' ')

print(num)
print(words)
```

Output:

```
# num = 1
# words = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```

Answer (score 2):

Non-regex solution:

```
>>> s = '1: foo bar baz # This is an example'
>>> a, _, b = s.partition(':')
>>> [int(a)] + b.partition('#')[0].split()
[1, 'foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```

Answer (score 1):

The trick here is to use lookeaheads: let's find either digits (followed by a colon) or words (followed by letters/spaces and a hash):

```
s = "1: foo bar baz # This is an example"
print re.findall(r'\d+(?=:)|\w+(?=[\w\s]*#)', s)
# ['1', 'foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```

The only thing that remains is to convert `"1"` to an int - but you can't do that with regexp.