# What is the Python equivalent of Perl 6's comb method?

Tags: python, raku

`comb` in Perl 6 is like a complement of `split`. Instead of choosing what to *exclude* from the results, you are choosing what to *include*. Is there a Python equivalent, and if so, what is it?

So far, all of my searching for "Python comb" gives me results related to "combinations", not "the complement of split".

Here is an example of it in Perl 6:

```
#!/bin/env perl6

my $text = "5 foos, 16 bars, 7 bazes";

my @result = $text.comb(/\d+/);  # \d matches numbers

say @result.join(" ");  # 5 16 7
```

Update based on feedback: `comb` is more like a complement of `split` than its "opposite".

Comment: looks like you need `str.join`?

Comment: But comb is not the opposite of split here, that's join. Comb just appears to be doing a search.

Comment: I think you're looking for `re.findall()`, which finds all the matches of a regular expression.

Comment: @DanielRoseman In Perl, split uses a pattern too. Sometimes the pattern is simply a string, but it can be a complicated multi-line pattern as well.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks! `re.findalll()` is what I ended up using. One caveat is that when capturing groups with quantifiers `(pattern)+`, only the last match of each group is returned. My more detailed case (not shown here) benefitted from the following Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21664367.

Comment: I think that's how quantified capture groups work in all regexp engines.

Comment: If you want everything, wrap it in another group: `((?:pattern)+)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `str.join` with `re.findall`

**Ex:**

```
import re
text = "5 foos, 16 bars, 7 bazes"
print(" ".join(re.findall(r"\d+", text)))
```

**Output:**

```
5 16 7
```